# Draw circle on canvas simulating animation android

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas

I need to draw an empty circle with a margin of 10 px. The problem that i've encountered is that i need to simulate the draw of the circle in 2 seconds and after that to start drawing on the top of it another one with another color. I'm using  a custom view and i've tried to implement my logic into onDraw method and invalidate the view every 50 milisecond. The problem is that i can't manage to draw the circle...i draw only crapy figures. Does somebody know how can i draw a circle without using the canvas.drawCircle method because that method is drawing the circle directly without animation.

My current code

```
 public class CustomAnimationView  extends View{

private Canvas canvas;
private int count = 0;
private Paint paint;
private int mLeft;
private int mRight;
private int mBottom;
private int mTop;


public CustomAnimationView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomAnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomAnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setAttributes(attrs);
}

private void setAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;

    if(paint == null){
        paint  = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    if(count<150){
            drawFirstQuarter(count);
    }

    count++;
}

public void drawFirstQuarter(int count){
     RectF oval = new RectF(mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom);
     canvas.drawArc(oval, 90, 30, true, paint);
}


public void setRect(int top, int bottom, int left, int right){
    mBottom = bottom;
    mTop = top;
    mLeft = left;
    mRight = right;
}
```

}

Right now I'm just tring to draw a bit of a circle.

Comment: Can you post the code of your current custom view?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I've solved it.
Here is a code sample

```
public class CustomAnimationView extends View{

    private Canvas canvas;
    private int mCount = 0;
    private Paint paint1;
    private Paint paint2;
    private RectF oval1;
    private Context context;
    private int mColorCount = 0;

    public CustomAnimationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomAnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomAnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        setAttributes(attrs);
    }

    private void setAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.canvas = canvas;

        if(paint1 == null){
            paint1  = new Paint();
            paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint1.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            paint1.setStrokeWidth(10);
        }

        if(paint2 == null){
            paint2  = new Paint();
            paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint2.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            paint2.setStrokeWidth(10);
        }


        if(mCount % 360 == 0 ){
            mColorCount++;
        }

        if(mColorCount % 2 == 0){
            paint1.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            paint2.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }else{
            paint2.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            paint1.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }

        if(oval1 == null)
            oval1 = new RectF(5,5,canvas.getWidth()-5, canvas.getHeight()-5);

        drawFirstQuarter(mCount, oval1);

    }

    public void drawFirstQuarter(int count, RectF oval){
         canvas.drawArc(oval, 90, 360, false, paint2);
         canvas.drawArc(oval, 90, count, false, paint1);
         if(mCount == 330)
             mCount = 0;
         else
             mCount += 30;
    }
```

}